# Normalize to 4NF?

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization

Given the following table:

```
Title    Session    Year     Credit
C21         2       2018       6
C21         3       2018       6
C21         4       2018       6
C21         2       2019       6
C21         3       2019       6
C21         4       2019       6
D22         2       2018       4 
D22         3       2018       4
D22         4       2018       4
D21         3       2019       4
D21         4       2019       4
```

With the relational schema : SUBJECT(title, session, year, credit)

Is it possible to normalize the above to 4NF?

The criteria to normalize to 4NF is that it need to meet BCNF and **multiple value of B exists for a single value of A given A->B**. I am having trouble understanding and applying the bold to the table.

My attempt:

The table have repeated attributes for session, year and credit. Based on the bold statement (and BCNF met), I will normalize it to 4NF

```
Title    Session   
C21         2   
C21         3      
C21         4    
D22         2  
D22         3   
D22         4  

Title    Year   
C21      2018  
C21      2019
D22      2018
D22      2019

Title    Credit 
C21        6  
D22        4
```

I am conflicting on the 3 decomposed table though because the 3 attributes (session, year, credit) do not look like independent relation to title.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Are you normalizing that value or a schema/variable that could hold that value? "4NF is that it need to meet BCNF and multiple value of B exists for a single value of A given A->B" That is not not clear or a definition of 4NF. Please find one in a textbook & apply it & ask a question when stuck. There's no point in continuing with this question because an answer is just to tell you to do that. Asking us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke example is too broad. Also your attempt needs to refer to the definition or published algorithm as justification or what you did is unjustified.

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--not all terms/notations are standard & we don't know exactly what algorithm/method you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when a process allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your textbook. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you're not sure it's right, ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re where you got stuck.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Whenever you want to normalize data relationships, the first thing you do is list all of the relationships.

- A subject has a title and credit hours.
- A subject has multiple sessions.
- A subject is taught in multiple years.
- A session is in a single year.

So, let's start with a Subject table.

```
Subject 
-------
Subject ID
Subject Title
Subject Credit Hours
```

Subject ID is a blind autoincrementing integer primary key.

Looks good so far.

Now, let's create a Session table.

```
Session
-------
Session ID
Session Number
Session Year
Subject ID (FK)
```

Session ID is another blind autoincrementing integer primary key.

We can break the Session table down to remove the repeating session numbers by moving the Subject ID foreign key to a junction table.

```
Session
-------
Session ID
Session Number
Session Year

SubjectSession
--------------
SubjectSession ID
Subject ID
Session ID
```

Looks good so far.  Let's fill the tables

```
Subject ID  |  Subject Title  |  Subject Credit Hours
----------------------------------------------------- 
         1  |       C21       |           6
         2  |       D21       |           4
         3  |       D22       |           4

Session ID  |  Session Number  |  Session Tear  
----------------------------------------------
         1  |         2        |      2018    
         2  |         3        |      2018   
         3  |         4        |      2018     
         4  |         2        |      2019      
         5  |         3        |      2019      
         6  |         4        |      2019   
       
SubjectSessionID  |  SybjectID  |  Session ID
---------------------------------------------
               1  |          1  |           1
               2  |          1  |           2
               3  |          1  |           3 
               4  |          1  |           4
               5  |          1  |           5
               6  |          1  |           6
               7  |          3  |           1
               8  |          3  |           2
               9  |          3  |           3
              10  |          2  |           5
              11  |          2  |           6
```

I don't think that the year needs to be broken out.  It's part of what defines a session, even though it repeats.

I don't know if this is 4NF, but this is as normalized as I would make it.

Comment: It feels like it is up to how the relational schema is interpreted to do the normalization?

Comment: @user3118602: Yes.  You have to get the correct relationships to get a somewhat correct normalization.

Comment: @user3118602: *"It feels like it is up to how the relational schema is interpreted to do the normalization?"* Yes. Normalization depends on what each column *means*. [See the end of this SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62430448/562459)

Answer (score -1):

```
-- Subject TITLE taught in year YEAR, session SESSION,
-- is worth CREDIT credits.
--
subject {TITLE, SESSION, YEAR, CREDIT}
```

Given the predicate, and the data sample, the obvious `FD` is `TITLE -> CREDIT`, so it is possible to decompose `subject` to:

```
r1 {TITLE, CREDIT}
r2 {TITLE, SESSION, YEAR}
```

When contemplating `NFs`, it is important to focus on predicates and constraints -- logic. Sample data is helpful, but rarely tells the whole story.  A table is in a specific `NF` for any set of valid rows, empty set included.

Based on the data sample, it looks possible to decompose `{TITLE, SESSION, YEAR}` into `{TITLE, SESSION}` and `{TITLE, YEAR}`, as in your attempt. More formally, it *looks as if* the join dependency

`* { {TITLE, SESSION}, {TITLE, YEAR} }` holds.

Let's see if I can verbalize this:

> If a (subject) *title* was taught in *session*, and a *title* was taught in a *year*, then that *title* was taught in that *session* in that *year*.

Does this make sense? Is it logical?

If this makes sense then your initial solution `{TITLE, SESSION}, {TITLE, YEAR}, {TITLE, CREDIT}`
is correct. However, what will happen in 2020, 2021? The rule states that if *title* C21 is taught in *year* 2021, it must be in *sessions* 2,3,4. Is this correct?

School assignments are hard, you often have to guess what the teacher was thinking. Sometimes I wonder if they were thinking at all. Guessing constraints from a small data sample is an extremely bad idea.

---

Here is my suggestion, the way I see it:

1. That join dependency *does not* hold.
2. FD `TITLE -> CREDIT` holds.

```
-- Subject TITLE is worth CREDIT credits.
--
subject {TITLE, CREDIT}
     PK {TITLE}


-- Subject TITLE was taught in year YEAR, session SESSION.
--
subject_ys {TITLE, SESSION, YEAR}
        PK {TITLE, SESSION, YEAR}
```

Both of these are now in `6NF` and therefore in: `5,4,BCNF,3,..`. That is *if and only if* I understand predicates and constraints properly. Take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029821/how-to-understand-the-5th-normal-form/18032875#18032875).

Comment: Thanks Damir. Regarding FDs, isn't TITLE -> YEAR, SESSION one of the FDs too? Sorry if this is a silly question, relatively new and will like to get it right.

Comment: @user3118602 Loosely speaking FD `X->Y` means: if you know X, you know Y. There are multiple `{YEAR, SESSION}` for a given `TITLE` in your example, so no.

Comment: @user3118602 If you are interested in NFs and database design for your own personal/professional projects then take a look at: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/262601/need-help-with-bcnf-decomposition-problem/262793#262793
If you have to pass an exam, then do as you must to pass.